# Using the DFS Method in C, how can I make it so there will be no user input

Tags: c

For my code, I am checking if the graph is connected using DFS. As of now it uses user input. I want it to not use user input for the 2D array (the matrix). What would I do to this part of `isConnected()` (see below) to fix it so I can use the global 2D array b instead of the global 2D array a

```
printf("\nEnter adjacency matrix : \n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
```

This is what I have so far

```
int a[20][20],reach[20],n;
int b[4][4] = { {0,1,1,1},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,1}};
void dfs(int v){
    int i;
    reach[v]=1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if(a[v][i]&&!reach[i]){
        printf("\n%d->%d",v,i);
        dfs(i);
    }
}
void isConnected(){
    int i,j,count=0;
    printf("\n no of vertices is 4 ");
    // scanf("%d",&n);
    int n = 4;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++){
        reach[i]=0;
        a[i][j]=0;
    }

    printf("\nEnter adjacency matrix : \n");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=n;j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    dfs(1);
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        if(reach[i])
            count++;
    if(count==n)
        printf("\nGraph is connected.");
    else
    printf("\nGraph is disconnected.");
}
```

To save some clutter I took out main which just calls the function to check if it is connected

Comment: Sorry if it is obvious, I still suck at the syntax of C but I have been stuck here for many hours

Comment: It's not obvious. The easy way is to use [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (VLA) syntax, but since VLA's are optional as of C11, you first need to determine whether your compiler supports VLAs.

Comment: Another observation: In C, array indexes are zero-based. Which means an array like `b[4]` is indexed from 0 to 3. So a loop like `for (i=1;i<=n;i++)` will access past the end of the array if `n` is 4. You either need to make the arrays bigger `b[5]` or change to the loops to `for (i=0;i<n;i++)`.